# Django's maximum verbosity useless: "ImportError: No module named apps"

Tags: python, django

I checked out some code and am trying to get it running, but whenever I `runserver`, I get the error message:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
ImportError: No module named apps
```

OK...not quite sure where to start debugging. How about more verbose:

```
$ python manage.py runserver --verbosity=3
ImportError: No module named apps
```

Gee, thanks Django. How do I start debugging this? I don't see "`apps`" in the `INSTALLED_APPS` or anything blatant.

Comment: So, what more do you expect? Django's verbosity setting relates to Django-specific error messages, it's not designed to babysit you through every single mistake you make. An `ImportError` has nothing to do with your installed apps, but it has everything to do with your python environment.

Comment: @knbk given Django's dynamic importing, I figured it was just Django dumping on me (the error message was also colored, which I don't seem to recall Python doing). While it's obvious for someone more experienced like yourself, alas, I'm not that good.

Comment: @knbk also, the error causing the ImportError (without *any* traceback) was actually because of one of my installed apps, specifically `django-grappelli`. I suppose in a broader context that's my Python environment...  Anyways, never knew that printing tracebacks was "babysitting".

Comment: Are you using Django <= 1.6? While your `INSTALLED_APPS` are imported by Django, it doesn't control where python searches to include them and whether they can be found.

Comment: @knbk 1.5. If Django is attempting to import modules, catching errors of same, then printing it's own styled error before dying, I'm still baffled why asking Django to be more verbose wouldn't cause it to be a little more obvious. Instead I need to have Python be verbose and tell me what Django's doing to get to the cause of the matter.

Comment: Probably, django-grappelli is trying to import `django.apps`, which doesn't exist until 1.7. You need to use an older version of grappelli that supports 1.5. So, this is the only output you're getting? I'm getting full tracebacks with Django by default, unless the exception occurs within a view - in which case it is just a 500 response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to whatever program you're running, you can also tell Python to be more verbose directly:

```
python -v manage.py runserver --verbosity=3
```

...or more with `-vvv` if you really need to see the value, reference count, and memory location of each individual integer and float get cleaned up.